# Как объединить две модели регрессии, с выбором через if и закрузкой в pickle

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Такая задачка примитивная,
Две модели  LinearRegression и RandomForestRegressor
как их состэкать в единую модель которую можно сохранять и загружать при помощи pickle , и при том
чтоб модель для предсказания выбиралась жестко в  зависимости от значения признака x:
при x<50 по линейной а  больше 50 по лесу

clf1 = LinearRegression()  - x <50

clf2 = RandomForestRegressor()  -   x=>50

newModel.predict(z)

Подскажите решение или предикторы что загуглить 
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Для разных строк (экземпляров) датасета должны вызываться разные регрессоры в зависимости от выполнения условий?

Comment: Да, именно так, вопрос скореее граматический
Мне бы создать новую модель на основе верхних двух и её уже дампить
Возможно ли сделать жестко детерминированный стекинг?

Позже приведу пример кода

Answer (score 0):

А что, условный оператор в Python уже запретили? Или вы учите ML не изучив предварительно хоть какой язык программирования?

```
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    if  x <50: 
        clf1 = LinearRegression()
        pickle.dump(clf1, f)
    else:
        clf2 = RandomForestRegressor()
        pickle.dump(clf2, f)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, что уделили время и даже код привели.
Ваш алгоритм в зависимости от параметра x дампит в файл одну из указанных моделей.
Как бы этот кусок кода с двумя предобученными моделями на соответствующих диапазонах данных "упаковать" в новую модель?
и, так как я лишь начинающий ,возможно ли такое?)

метод голосования VotingClassifier ввиду использования регрессии, как понимаю, здесь не подходит
Обучение модели нового леса на основе метапризнаков верхних двух моделей так понимаю ведет к некоторому усреднению значений.
Или же это наиболее верный путь?

Comment: наверно решением будет создать новый объект класса модели в него передать две обученные модели, добавить условие выбора и уже этот объект дампить

Comment: Oй, что-то мне подсказывает, что вы как-то очень не четко формулируете задачу. Может вы имеете ввиду, что две модели вы обучаете, а потом, на этапе собственно классификации вам в зависимости от некоего значения параметра Х надо выбрать ту или иную из пердобученных моделей?  Если это так, то дампите обе модели после обучения, а потом на этапе классификации проверяете свой параметр и в зависимости от его значения вызываете на исполнение либо одну из моделей либо другую. Ну, в крайнем случае, передаете в predict self-параметром нужную вам модель.